# Make external module eliglible for Angular AOT compiler

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I am trying to develop angular application which would be combined from multiple repositories. My catalog structure is:

```
git_repo_1-bootstrap-module
|                        |
|                        src
|
git_repo_2-lazy-loaded-module
|        |
|        src
|
git_repo_3-lazy-loaded-module
        |
        src
```

package.json in the bootstrap module have dependencies to child modules:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "module-1": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/my-project/module-1.git",
    "module-2": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/my-project/module-2.git",
    //another dependencies
  },
```

Now, I am lazy-loading child modules as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', loadChildren: '../../node_modules/my-project-module1/src/app/home.module#HomeModule' },
    {path: 'account-settings', loadChildren: '../../node_modules/my-project-module2/src/app/account-settings.module#AccountSettingsModule' }
];
```

Everything works with Just In Time (JIT) compilation. The problem starts with the Ahead of Time (AOT):

```
ERROR in ./compiled/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/path-to-my-project/compiled/node_modules/krolewicz-ol-admin-home/src/app/home.module.ngsummary.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Loader.trackSymbolRootDecl (/path-to-my-project/node_modules/src/Loader.ts:157:23)
    at Loader.trackSymbolRootDecl (/path-to-my-project/node_modules/src/Loader.ts:168:19)
    at /path-to-my-project/node_modules/src/Loader.ts:120:29
 @ ./src/main.browser.aot.ts 10:0-78
```

I have no idea how for what are used `.ngsummary.json` files, and how to make my external modules eliglible for AOT compilator?

I am using https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter as a boiler plate. So every configuration file is as in this repo.

**Edit:**
as @yesides asking, I am adding my `main.module.ts` code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

import { MainRoutingModule } from './main-routing.module';

import { AuthGuard, CognitoService, LoginComponent } from './login';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ MainComponent ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MainRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CognitoService,
    AuthGuard
  ]
})
export class MainModule {}
```

Comment: **SSH** is configured?

Comment: I don't have problem with downloading packages from git. As I wrote, with JIT compilation everything works. I am able to install and start my project. I cannot compile it with AOT.

Comment: Could you post your main app module?

Comment: Sure. I have just edited my answer. You can find out how my main module looks.